# rational application developer update to 8.5

Tags: rad

I have RAD 8.0.4 installed on my machine. I want to update to 8.5. Do I have to install from scratch? The update manager has 8.0.4.1 available, but does not list 8.5. Does anybody know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that works like that.

Check this link from developerWorks: 
[Upgrade from 8.0.4 to 8.5.1 - blocker](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014934249&ps=100)